# Odoo 11: How to correctly implement @api.onchange?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, computed-field

I want to compute a telephone number, if the number in the 8 position is either "0" or "1" I want to print  just the last 4 numbers with a  "(3)" before them, otherwise just print the 4 numbers, but what is happening is that my code is printing "0.0" and I don't know why, I'll appreciate your help...

This is my python code:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"

    marcado_rapido = fields.Float("MarcadoRapido",compute='_compute_marcado_rapido')
    @api.onchange("emp.marcado_rapido")
    def onchange_compute_marcado_rapido(self):
        for num in self:
            num = "809-257-1457"
            if num[8] in ('0','1'):
                "(3)"+num[8:]
```

This is my xml code:

```xml
<td>
    <t t-foreach="env['hr.employee'].search([('department_id', '=', dep.id)])" t-as="emp">
        <div class="contact_form">
            <img t-if="emp.image" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % to_text(emp.image)"/>
            <div class="bloqueP">
                <div class="bloque" t-field="emp.marcado_rapido"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you use a float field for phone numbers? Shouldn't you use char fields for that?

Answer (score 0):

[@onchange](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/odoo/api.py#L170) only supports simple field names, dotted names (fields of relational fields e.g. `partner_id.tz`) are not supported and will be ignored

You can check the official documentation on how the [onchange](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly) decorator works and what are the limitations.

`0.0` is the default value for float fields and the value of `marcado_rapido` is computed using `_compute_marcado_rapido` function. If the field updated in onchange method depends on `marcado_rapido` field value, you can compute its value using the same method

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `compute` decoration instead of `onchange`, but `compute` method aproach always depend in someone else field. My sugestion is use a another computed field, something like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'
    
    # If your number contains special characters(like '-') you should use `Char` insted of `float`
    num_telefono = fields.Char('Num. Telefono')
    marcado_rapido = fields.Char('MarcadoRapido', compute='_compute_marcado_rapido')

    @api.depends('num_telefono')
    def _compute_marcado_rapido(self):
        for rec in self:
            num = rec.num_telefono[-4:]
            rec.marcado_rapido = '(3){}'.format(num) if num[:1] in ('0','1') else num
```

Now you can call `marcado_rapido` from your XML.

I hope this answer can be helful for you.